# How to select only one entry based on each parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This has probably been asked before, but I have no idea on how to find it in the first place.

In the following query (with respective returned values):

```
select * from tbChapter where idLesson in(12, 13)
```

-- Result --

```
id    idLesson    name              sequence
52    12          Intro             1
53    12          Chapter One       2
54    12          Chapter Two       3
55    13          Intro             1
56    13          Chapter One       2
57    13          Chapter Two       3
58    13          Chapter Three     4
```

I want to get only the last entry for each idLesson, for example:

-- Expected result --

```
id    idLesson    name              sequence
54    12          Chapter Two       3
58    13          Chapter Three     4
```

How can I proceed?

Ps: I'l actually replace `where idLesson in(12, 13)` with subquery that will return dozens of `idLesson` values.

Comment: `GROUP BY idLesson HAVING sequence = MAX(sequence)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  select * from tbChapter  where id in
  (select MAX(id) from tbChapter group by idLesson)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * 
from tbChapter as a
where sequence = (select max(sequence)
                  from tbChapter as b
                  where a.id_lesson = b.id_lesson)
```

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way is to use window functions.  Here is an example:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, max(sequence) over (partition by idLesson) as maxs
      from tblChapter c
     ) c
where sequence = maxs;
```

A more creative way that might perform better under some circumstances is to use `cross apply`:

```
select c.*
from (select distinct idLesson from tblChapter) l cross apply
     (select top 1 c*
      from tblChapter c
      where c.idLesson = l.idLesson
      order by sequence desc
     ) c;
```

Note that the first subquery can be replaced by a table that has all the lessons, with one per row.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   Max(id),
   idlesson,
   name,
   Max(sequence)
FROM
   tbChapter
WHERE
   idLesson in(12, 13)
GROUP BY
   idlesson,
   name
```